# why tr has padding even though i make that padding zero

Tags: css

This is a screenshot of my page.

[image]

I put the mouse on `td class style21` to show you that this class has no padding.

this td exists in tr which has a class = `style24`. I make the padding for that style = 0 and the margion = 0 but as you see that tr still has padding .

why please?

#### please don't suggest a completely new css because I would do that myself but I am supporting an application which already exist

Comment: I'm pretty sure that **you won't have any answer**, just some suggestion, OK.

Comment: @KingKing that is a shock . why please?

Comment: @user3432257 remove the height from the table.

Comment: @RoyiNamir there is no height in my table. which class exactly are you talking about please?

Comment: put the viewsource in jsfiddle/jsbin and upload it here.

Comment: Or provide a link to the page?

Comment: have you tried removing the border in `style21`, making the <td> width 100% and adding border-collapse:collapse?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I will try that although it is a asp.net. Also, I found this `height: 66px;` in `style10` which is the table style. I removed that value, but nothing happened

Comment: @sideroxylon the boarding is just 1px.

Comment: We are not magicians. send jsbin

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes I will try sir.

Comment: you can write inline css to overirde the previous one..

Comment: @RoyiNamir this is it http://jsfiddle.net/5sYF5/

Comment: @KingKing I added a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/5sYF5/

Comment: @Talknerdytome this is a link to my style http://jsfiddle.net/5sYF5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS I said , remove the height for the table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it goes on that website. but on my machine it is still. Also, do you think that this space is 700px? the 700px is too large for that space, right? Secondly, do you think that I have to remove that cach maybe it works on my machine? thanks

Comment: @user3432257 padding are not created automatically. they created to consempate for something. like if you have TD height or table height

Comment: @RoyiNamir if that `style1` is affecting that. why chrome webkit didn't show it to me in the styles section please? as i told you, the padding is gone in the jsdfill but not on my machine and I have give you the whole code

Comment: @user3432257 those sound like design considerations, for which you are on the wrong site

Comment: I tried to change the height to 100px and to 300px but nothing changed in the browser, help please. and yes the jfiddle website is working, i will accept ur andswer

Comment: there is something wrong going on. the 700px is too large for that padding. right?

Comment: The padding on td is adjusted to make the entire table 700px.  You have 9 rows, so each row has padding added to make it approx 77px.  If you had 10 rows, it would be 70px, etc.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not perfect, you could try using the `!important` exception in CSS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I would use it and I know it. but first lets try for another suggestions, because I hate to use it.